# How to redirect dd progress in terminal to a log.txt file but still display it on the terminal during the process?

Tags: command-line, bash, stdout

Here is my script :-

```
sudo mate-terminal --geometry=50x10 -x sh -c "dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb status=progress 2>&1 | tee log.txt | md5sum > hash.txt | sha1sum > hash1.txt"
```

I've seen people giving this suggestion all the time; putting 2>&1. But this will only display the progress in the log.txt file and the terminal will display nothing. Here's a picture of what the progress look like on the log.txt file.

[image: logfile]

If I remove `2>&1` and just go with

```
command | tee log.txt
```

Only the terminal will show the progress and nothing will display in the `log.txt` file

I've also tried:-

```
(command 2>&1) | log.txt

command 2> | log.txt
```

and many more I can't recall. So can someone help me?

Comment: The command you want is `script`; read about it.

Answer (score 3):

The progress is output to STDERR rather than STDOUT. You could get something like what you want by doing `tail -f` on the file being written to like this:

```
mate-terminal --geometry=50x10 -x sh -c 'tail -f log.txt'
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb status=progress 2> log.txt"
```

`tail -f log.txt` will print everything being written to `log.txt` to the new smaller terminal and run as a background process so you can issue more commands while it runs.
`2>` sends STDERR stream to `log.txt`. If there is any output on STDOUT it will display in the terminal from which the command or script is run.

Comment: Hi @Zanna, I remember you from my older question :) This doesn't work for me. If you can refer to this picture http://pictub.club/image/HLUp8 I want to redirect the progress to the blue terminal. The black terminal I use to execute my tools. Now the progress is displayed on the black terminal and also it also logs it on the .txt file but I wanted it so that it display on the blue terminal. Oh and I've edited your script a bit changing from     "sudo bash -c" to     "sudo mate-terminal --geometry=50x10 -x sh -c"

Comment: @Najmi ah I see :) how this could sort-of work then, is if you send the `tail -f` command to the other terminal (where you want to see the progress) - I'll see if I can fix it. But my answer is just an imperfect workaround anyway, now @muru has given you the real answer and taught us both how to do it correctly.

Comment: I'm reading on dc3dd right now. Seems promising. Will write back if it works

Comment: @Najmi edited, hope it is useful. I still think muru's answer is better though :)

Answer (score 2):

Redirect both stderr and stdout with `|&` in bash:

```
sudo mate-terminal --geometry=50x10 -x bash -c "dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb status=progress |& tee log.txt"
```

Comment: it worksss ! But.... when I add | md5sum > hash.txt | sha1.txt > hash1.txt, it doesn't display the progress on the terminal anymore. Got any idea ?

Comment: What exactly is `| md5sum > hash.txt | sha1.txt >hash1.txt` supposed to be doing?

Comment: to log the md5 and sha1 hash value. I'm developing a forensic tools and I need the hash value is to verify that the cloned drive is the same as the drive being clone

Comment: Hash values of what, exactly? What do you imagine is happening in that pipeline?